# contact form with Phonegap Build (that doesn't take the user out of the app and that can store the message if offline)

Tags: cordova

I would like to create a contact form within my app, which uses Jquery mobile 1.4 + phonegap-build 3.3+, for the users to contact me.

But I am not sure how to send the message...Ajax request to a server script, or with a Phonegap Plugin maybe ?
I have these 3 criteria :

1. I don't want the user to be taken out of the app to his email app. So I would like to send the message from within the app with just by tapping a "send" button and that's all.
2. I also need the message to be stored if the user is offline, and to be sent later when his phone is back online.
3. I also need to get the user's email address in order to be able to answer him.

First option : A pluging like emailComposer  [here](https://github.com/jcjee/email-composer/tree/40e4b39dbd0d8605e4859b137d03f4a47262a35d)  ?

Second option : a request to a server script ?

What's best ?

Thanks

Comment: I wonder in both option if your 2nd crteria can be checked!! I belive you'll required some other approach to fill the 2nd criteria.you'll need to manually check for the offline mode, and handle coming back online

Comment: @AtanuCSE yes, I think I might have to use second option, and if offline, record the message in Localstorage, check if online at next app launch and send the message. Do you know where I can find examples of client- and server- side script ?

Comment: Yeah may be I can help you with that. Wait I will give you an example in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you asked for client - server script example in comments, here is one using jquery ajax call to a php script in server.

Cleint / phonegap app:

```
$('#sendlink').on("vclick", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var data={
                    userEmail: userEmail,
                    subject: subject,
                    destEmail: destEmail,
                    body: body            
                   }
            function sendToServer() {
                return $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://yoururl.com/mail.php',
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    data: data
                });
            }
            sendToServer().done(handleSuccess);
            sendToServer().fail(handleError);
            function handleSuccess(data /* , textStatus, jqXHR */ ) {
                console.log("Message successfully sent");
            }
            function handleError(data , textStatus, jqXHR  ) {
                console.log("Error when sending the message : ");
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data.response);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(jqXHR);
            }
        });
```

Server side:

```
<?php
#if you also need this script to respond to other domains, add those header lines
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
if($_POST) {
    $userEmail=$_POST['userEmail'];
    $subject=$_POST['subject'];
    $destEmail=$_POST['destEmail'];
    $body=$_POST['body'];

    $response = mail($destEmail, $subject, $body, "From:" . $userEmail);
    echo $response;
    exit();
}
?>
```

This is an example. Try searching ajax call to server and learn how to send and receive xml response. in php script you will need to send some xml responce. Or you can use JSON instead of XML.

Comment: great, thanks I going to try an implement it tomorrow, I'll keep you posted, thanks for your help.